# Button code is run when I CREATE the button. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When inserting a button into the page with jQuery, the function for the button runs when the button is **created** (and injected into the page), not when it is clicked. How do I make the code only run when the button is clicked?

Code which creates the button:

```
var buttonName = "One";
var $input = $('<input type="button" value=\'' + buttonName + '\' onclick=\'' + openSerial(buttonName)  + '\'>');
$input.appendTo("#ports");
console.log("fn: portScan: ",$input);
```

When this button is created (via another page event), the function openSerial() executes.

I want openSerial to only execute when the button is pressed. How is this done?

Comment: `openSerial(buttonName)` actually calls the function, are you trying to reference it?

Comment: Don't use the onclick property. Instead, use jQuery's .click or .on() functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `onclick` is basically a function body stored in an HTML attribute. As such, when creating such a thing programmatically, you would write it out using a string. The JS engine will read it in and execute it when clicked.

By *not* using a string, you are actually calling the function when you think you're passing it in as the `onclick`. Consider that bit by itself:

```
openSerial(buttonName)
```

If you were to stick to your current approach, it would need to be written like:

```
var $input = $('<input type="button" value="' + buttonName + '" onclick="openSerial(' + buttonName + ')">');
```

That said, `onclick` should really not be used anymore, and event handlers should be attached using code. This is all the more true in your case because 1) you're creating this button in code and 2) you're already using jQuery.

As such, this would be more appropriate:

```
var buttonName = "One";
var $input = $('<input />')
    .attr('type', 'button')
    .val(buttonName)
    .on('click', function () {
        openSerial(buttonName);
        // alternatively, you could read the button name back out of the value
        // openSerial($(this).val());
    });
$input.appendTo("#ports");
```

Answer (score 4):

You're calling the function when you do `openSerial(buttonName)`.

You're using jQuery, don't try to inline the value or the event handlers.

Change

```
var $input = $('<input type="button" value=\'' + buttonName + '\' onclick=\'' + openSerial(buttonName)  + '\'>');
```

to

```
var $input = $('<input type="button">')
.val(buttonName)
.click(function(){ openSerial(buttonName) });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're CALLING the function, since you're doing string concatenation:

```
var foo = "bar" + baz() + "qux";
                  ^^^^^---execute function, concatenate result
```

versus

```
var foo = "bar baz() qux"
               ^^^^^---create string with the letters b, a, z, etc..
```

You need

```
var $input = $('<input ..snip...] onclick=\'openSerial(' + buttonName + ')\'>');
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead.

Comment: Good explanation of the bug but please propose a code which isn't bad practice.